# C pointer, struct and fwrite

Tags: c, pointers, struct, fwrite, fread

I'm currently trying to write and read a simple linked list into a file, but it doesn't really seem to work and I'm not sure if it is even possible.

```
typedef struct flug
{
    int            flugnummer;
    char            flugziel[50];
    enum TAG        flugtag;
    int            flugzeit_stunde;
    int            flugzeit_minute;
    int            gateway;
    char            status[10];
    struct flug    *next;
}FLUG;

typedef FLUG *ELEM_ZGR;
```

I fear the problem might be that I'm not only writing chars, but int .. and especially enums, too.

```
int fluege_sichern() {
ELEM_ZGR curr;

FILE *fp;
char* tag;

curr = first;

if (fopen_s(&fp, datei,"a+b") != 0) {
    printf("\nDatei %s nicht zum Anhaengen zu oeffnen",datei);
    PAUSE;
    exit(1);
}

for(curr = first; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
    fwrite(curr, sizeof(FLUG), 1, fp);
}

    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

This is supposed to be the function to write the elements into a file as binaries. I don't get any errors in this function.

```
void fluege_laden() {
ELEM_ZGR curr;
FILE *fp;
int i = 0;

if (fopen_s(&fp, datei,"rb") != 0) {
    printf("\nDatei %s nicht zum Lesen zu oeffnen",datei);
    PAUSE;
    exit(1);
}

while(1) {
     fread(&curr, sizeof(FLUG), 1, fp);
     printf("\n%d", curr->flugnummer);
     //fluege_sortieren(curr);
}
}
```

I get the error when I try to print out curr->flugnummer.

Ok so I changed the two functions a little, but it still doesn't seem to work. I'm sorry, I don't seem to get it...

[EDIT2] Another version that doesn't work:

```
void fluege_laden() {
    ELEM_ZGR curr;  // <<<- allocate an actual struct here rather than just a pointer
    FILE *fp;

    int i = 0;
    curr = first;

    if (fopen_s(&fp, datei,"rb") != 0) {
        printf("\nDatei %s nicht zum Lesen zu oeffnen",datei);
        PAUSE;
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1) {
        fread(curr, sizeof(FLUG), 1, fp);
        printf("\n%d", curr->flugnummer);   // <<<
        printf("\n%s", curr->flugziel);
        //fluege_sortieren(curr);
        PAUSE;
    }

}

int fluege_sichern() {
ELEM_ZGR curr;
FILE *fp;

curr = first;

if (fopen_s(&fp, datei,"a+b") != 0) {
    printf("\nDatei %s nicht zum Anhaengen zu oeffnen",datei);
    PAUSE;
    exit(1);
}

for(curr = first; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
    fwrite(curr, sizeof(FLUG), 1, fp);
}

    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It's enough to `fread(curr)` and not `fread(&curr)`. Also be careful with the pointers, as `next` will be compromised after writing it and reading it back.

Comment: @foxx1337: `curr` is a wild pointer, so although you're right about removing the dereference, it's still not going to work.

Answer (score 3):

`curr` is an uninitialised pointer (a `FLUG*`) and is therefore not pointing to valid memory when `fread()` is called. Writing to invalid memory is undefined behaviour (the program could seg fault or execute incorrectly or worst case execute correctly). Either create a stack allocated object (of type `FLUG`) or dynamically allocate memory for `curr`.

Personally, I find it very confusing when a pointer is `typedef`d as at the point of use it is not obvious that the variable is a pointer:

```
ELEM_ZGR curr;
```

The following is unambiguous:

```
FLUG* curr; /* Or just 'FLUG curr;' for this case. */
```

Check the result of [`fread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) to ensure the program is not operating on stale data:

```
FLUG curr;
while (1 == fread((&curr, sizeof(FLUG), 1, fp))
{
    printf("\n%d", curr.flugnummer);
}
```

---

*(In response to the question edit)*

In short, change:

```
fwrite(curr, sizeof(FLUG*), 1, fp);
fread(&curr, sizeof(FLUG*), 1, fp);
```

to:

```
fwrite(curr, sizeof(FLUG), 1, fp);
fread(curr, sizeof(FLUG), 1, fp);
```

In both cases, `curr` is a `FLUG*` and is pointing to valid memory for storing a `FLUG` so you need to read the `sizeof(FLUG)`, not the `sizeof(FLUG*)`. The typical size for a pointer of any type is 4 or 8 bytes. On my x86 box it is 4 bytes and the size of a `FLUG` is 88 bytes. The `size` argument to both `fwrite()` and `fread()` instructs the number of bytes to read and write:

```
fwrite(curr, sizeof(FLUG), 1, fp); /* write 88 bytes to fp from address curr. */
fread(curr, sizeof(FLUG), 1, fp); /* read 88 bytes from fp and write to the
                                     address beginning at curr. */
```

Passing the address of `&curr` to `fread()` means a `FLUG**` is being passed to `fread()` which is incorrect.

Comment: But how do I get the FLUG struct into the pointer and the other way around? Is that even possible?

Comment: @user854699, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have a pointer which I use to go through the list. As you guys said I can't put these pointers into the file. I need to put in the structs, but how do I convert the pointers to structs?

Comment: @user854699, when writing to the file you need to pass the _address_ of the `struct` to `fwrite()`. A pointer holds the address of a variable (commonly stated as _points to_). In your case, a `FLUG*` holds the address of a `FLUG`. When calling `fwrite()` you pass in a `FLUG*`, the address of a `FLUG`.

Comment: That apparently doesn't work. I get the error "Debug Assertion Failed!". Thanks for the information, though. Now I'm a little less stupid concerning this stuff. Still don't knof why it won't work though.

Answer (score 2):

In the read routine `ELEM_ZGR curr;` is just an uninitialised pointer. You need to do something like this:

```
void fluege_laden() {
    FLUG curr;  // <<<- allocate an actual struct here rather than just a pointer
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;

    if (fopen_s(&fp, datei,"rb") != 0) {
        printf("\nDatei %s nicht zum Lesen zu oeffnen",datei);
        PAUSE;
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1) {
        fread(&curr, sizeof(FLUG), 1, fp); // <<<
        printf("\n%d", curr.flugnummer);   // <<<
        //fluege_sortieren(curr);
    }
}
```

Also, in the write routine you need to write the whole struct, e.g.

```
int fluege_sichern() {
    ELEM_ZGR curr;
    FILE *fp;
    char* tag;

    curr = first;

    if (fopen_s(&fp, datei,"a+b") != 0) {
        printf("\nDatei %s nicht zum Anhaengen zu oeffnen",datei);
        PAUSE;
        exit(1);
    }

    for(curr = first; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        fwrite(curr, sizeof(FLUG), 1, fp); // <<<- curr is already a pointer - do not dereference here !
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whoa! Think what memory you're reading into there. Your `fread` is asking for data to get dumped in some random location (because curr is uninitialised, so points to memory that probably doesn't exist in your process). You need to allocate some FLUGs and read into them.

Another problem is that you shouldn't be writing pointers to file; the data only has meaning within your process. When you read back the FLUGs, at the very least, you should set cur->next to something sensible (like the next FLUG!).

Answer (score 0):

You are writing pointers to a file, called a *shallow copy*.  Pointers are not transferable, you need to write code to do a *deep copy*.  Either that, or use something like JSON or YAML.

Comment: Uhm .. I'll take the deep copy way, but I don't know how to do this. How do I convert the values from the pointer to the struct?

Comment: You need to allocate a memory buffer for each value and copy them specifically, then write the buffer.  Obviously you will need a structure to your file to be able to identify each component.  When reading back-in you need to read each value back in to a prepared memory area, so you might need to store the size of each component as well.  A lot of work!  JSON and YAML do all that for you, but as text (so they can be slow).

Comment: I can't do that as this is sort of a thing I have to do for college. Is there no way to save this data without the use of extern sources?

Comment: If you can use an external sorce then you have to write it yourself!  Welcome to C.

Comment: I can't imagine that it is that difficult. This is a exercise for basic course for C.